# Ruby - How to capture and store a session cookie on login?

Tags: ruby, http, cookies

I need to accomplish what the following curl command is doing in Ruby.  The curl command logs in to my website and stores all the cookies returned.  Amongst which is a session cookie that I need to execute further restful stuff though my API.  How do I do that in Ruby?

```
curl --user-agent "MyUserAgent" --cookie-jar cookiefile -o - --data 'userid=myemail%40hostname.com&passwd=mypassword' https://.../login.jsp
```

My current Ruby code, which works in terms of successfully logging in looks like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI.parse("https://.../login.jsp")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.set_form_data('userid' => 'myemail@hostname.com', 'passwd' => 'mypassword')
res = https.request(req)
puts res
```

What I get from "puts res" in the last line is the response object "#< Net::HTTPFound:0x007fb6a3bd40a0>"

Are the cookies in the response object that I can access them with some method?  I'm not real clear on how I get my cookies.  Unlike the curl, I don't need to put them in a file.  I'd happily put them in a hash, but I don't know how to access them to do so.  Suggestions appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the best way to achieve cURL-like behavior in Ruby is to use Curb (cURL for Ruby).  Here's my solution:

```
require 'curb'
def debug_handler
    return ->(data_type, data) {
    puts data
}
end

c =Curl::Easy.new
url = "https://some.domain.com/login.jsp"
headers={}
headers['User-Agent']='MyAgent'

creds = [Curl::PostField.content("userid","username@domain.com")]
creds << Curl::PostField.content("passwd","supersecretpassword")

c.url = url
c.headers=headers
c.enable_cookies=true
c.verbose=true
c.on_debug(&debug_handler)
c.http_post(creds)
response=c.response_code
puts response
```